# Have systemd timer to run immediately when started?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I have a timer that should run every 60 seconds like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Trigger test timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=60
```

The timer triggers after waiting 60 seconds. But I want it to trigger immediately on start and then again at 60 second intervals. How do I specify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
[Unit]
Description=Trigger test timer

[Timer]
OnActiveSec=0
OnCalendar=*:0/1
```

The OnActiveSec makes the timer run immediately and the OnCalendar makes it run every minute. The time between the first and second run is random though.

Answer (score -1):

On some systems I use:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/1
```

This will run something approximately once per minute

Comment: But I believe that will wait till the next full minute to run.

Comment: Are you running a `*.service` that takes longer than 60s to execute, and you want multiple instances of the service, each one starting 60s from the start of the previous one?

Comment: No. The service only takes a split second to run. But it must ran at times 0, 60, 120, ... The first run is important.